# LEFT JOIN : is there a way to reduce the line numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I work on a software that allows users to manage estates they want to sell. I have a database like this (simple exemple) :

```
estates
-------------
id
price


photos
-------------
photoName
estateId


documents
-------------
docName
estateId
```

I'd like to get, in one request, all the informations of an estate (let's say id = 1), its photos and its documents, so I do something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM estates
LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.estateId = id
LEFT OUTER JOIN documents ON documents.estateId = id
WHERE id = 1
```

Which returns something like :

```
id | price | photoName | estateId | docName 
----------------------------------------------
1  | 10000 | photo1.jpg| 1        | doc1.pdf
1  | 10000 | photo1.jpg| 1        | doc2.pdf
1  | 10000 | photo1.jpg| 1        | doc3.pdf
1  | 10000 | photo2.jpg| 1        | doc1.pdf
1  | 10000 | photo2.jpg| 1        | doc2.pdf
1  | 10000 | photo2.jpg| 1        | doc3.pdf

(assuming estate n°1 has 2 photos and 3 docs for the exemple)
```

Then, with some PHP script, I loop through the result to get only unique results and that's it, I loaded my estate with only one request (which is faster than launching 3 requests).

But that was only a simple exemple. In the real database, I have a LOT of other tables that I want to load, with a LOT of values inside. So much tables that the same type of request returns over 2,000,000 rows for only one estate. Which is, believe me or not, very long to load ^^'.

So I was wondering if there where some kind of magical thing that could give me a result like this :

```
id | price | photoName | estateId | docName 
----------------------------------------------
1  | 10000 | photo1.jpg| 1        | doc1.pdf
1  | 10000 | photo2.jpg| 1        | doc2.pdf
1  | 10000 | NULL*     | 1        | doc3.pdf

*NULL or whatever you want, I don't care.
```

So a request where the number of lines returned is the number of lines of the column with the most values (in the exemple, there are more docs than photos, so there are as much rows as docs).

Does something like this exists ?

~ MetalFox Dioxymore

Comment: Maybe you should try to avoid returning all data in a single query and to execute multiple statements: one for the photo list, another for the photo details, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated and it uses variables, but the answer is "yes":

```
select e.*,
       max(photoname) as photoname, max(docname) as docname)
from estates e join
     ((select p.estateid, p.photoname, NULL as docname, (@rnp := @rnp + 1) as seqnum
       from photos p cross join
            (select @rnp := 0) params
       where p.estateid = 1
      ) union all
      (select d.estateid, NULL, d.docname, (@rnd := @rnd + 1) as seqnum
       from documents d cross join
            (select @rnd := 0) params
       where d.estateid = 1
      )
     ) dp
     on dp.estateid = e.estateid
group by e.stateid, dp.seqnum
order by e.stateid, dp.seqnum;
```

This adds an enumerated value to the photos and documents for a given estate.  These are then aggregated.

Comment: That seems to work ! There are little mistakes in the answer (a parenthesis somwhere, no aliases for photos) but hey, that looks AWESOME ! Thank you ! I will benchmark this, but it can't be slower than 2,000,000 rows x).

Comment: @MetalFoxDoS, even if it takes a little longer (and it will take, as it adds another filter on top of your already processed result), think about the memory savings of loading the smaller recordset unto your application's memory.

Comment: IF the expected result was optimal this answer would be great, but the expected result isn't optimal. In PHP you could be looping through smaller arrays using separate queries. i.e. the assumption that one large matrix with blank cells is the way to go needs to be challenged

Answer (score 1):

You can even reduce this to one row per estate by simple aggregation.

```
SELECT
  e.*, 
  group_concat(distinct p.photoname) as photonames, 
  group_concat(distinct d.docname) as docnames
FROM estates e
LEFT OUTER JOIN photos p ON p.estateId = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN documents d ON d.estateId = e.id
WHERE e.id = 1
GROUP BY e.id;
```

This gives you strings such as `'photo1.jpg,photo2.jpg'` and `'doc1.pdf,doc2.pdf,doc3.pdf'`. Use PHP's `explode` function to get arrays from the strings.

As to performance: The above produces a large intermediate result set due to joining all photos with all docs etc. So using subqueries instead may be faster. And the use of DISTINCT is no longer needed - a good indicator for a more straight-forward way to retrieve the data.

```
SELECT
  e.*, 
  (select group_concat(p.photoname) from photos p where p.estateId = e.id) as photonames, 
  (select group_concat(d.docname) from documents d where d.estateId = e.id) as docnames 
FROM estates e
WHERE e.id = 1;
```

One more remark: With many photos and docs or large file names, you may need to extend the maximum allowed length for GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;
```

Comment: group_concat would be the way to do it in my opinion however performance does take a little hit but it would appear not as bad as gordon's sub selected unions and counters above.  Personally though I'd go with separate queries more flexibility and better ability to prepare for performance going forward.

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` calls, otherwise you'll get duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar: You are right of course; I missed that. I'll edit my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

```
SELECT e.id, p.photoName  FROM Estates e  
LEFT JOIN Photos p on  p.estateId = e.id
WHERE e.id = 1
UNION ALL

SELECT e.id, d.docName FROM Estates e  
LEFT JOIN Documents d on  d.estateId = e.id
WHERE e.id = 1
```

See here using SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79ce2/7